# rm( ) everything except specific object

Tags: r, set-difference

Does someone have an idea about how can I remove everything in R except one object?  Normally, to remove everything I code:

```
rm(list=ls())
```

So I tried:

```
rm(c(list=ls()-my_object))
```

but it didn’t work.

Comment: `rm(list = setdiff(ls(), "my_object") )`

Comment: @SymbolixAU: post that as an answer

Comment: you could also do `rm(list=ls()[!ls() %in% 'myobject'])`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `setdiff()` function shows the difference between sets, so we can use this to give the difference between all the objects (`ls()`), and the object you want to keep. For example

```
## create some objects
df <- data.frame()
v <- as.numeric()

# show everything in environment
objects()
# [1] "df" "v"

## or similarly
ls()
# [1] "df" "v"

## the setdiff() funciton shows the difference between two sets
setdiff(ls(), "df")
# [1] "v"

# so we can use this to remove everything except 'df'
rm(list = setdiff(ls(), "df"))
objects()
# [1] "df"
```

Comment: I seem to be attracting a lot of down-votes recently, looks like I've got a fan

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it, is pretty much identical to everyone else, but I tend to gravitate towards logical indices usually...

for a single object, using a logical index

```
rm(list=ls()[ls()!= "object_I_want"])
```

or this works for multiple objects even though it returns an error message

```
rm(list=ls()[ls()!= c("object_I_want1", "object_I_want2")])
```

if you only have a few objects in the workspace you could count and use their numeric index

```
ls();
#returns all objects in alphabetical order
# [1] "object_I_dont_want"  "object_I_want"  "object_I_dont_want"
rm(list=ls()[-2])
```

You don't technically need to use ls(). If for any reason you need to keep a running tally of the objects you want to keep, or you already have a set of objects you want to keep or get rid of, or whatever, you could just use an exclusive list sort of like this
*although technically it will also leave the object used as the subseting index as well.

```
exsubset = ls()[ls()!= c("object.I.want1", "object_I_want2")];
rm(list=exsubset)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it was asked a long ago. My answer may help others in future,
Suppose you want to remove everything from your environment except `obj1` and `obj2`

```
x<- which(ls()=="obj1"|ls()=="obj2")
ls1<- ls()[-x]
rm(list = ls1)
```